# Oracle Live SQL : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis -

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, create-table

I saw many others opened a question related to same problem however none of the answer addresses to the problem I have.

I am running below code on Oracle Live SQL and getting the error

> *ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis*

```
create table CUST_ORDER (
    ord_id NUMBER(38) CONSTRAINT cusordtb_ordid_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    cust_id NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
    order_date DATE(12) NOT NULL
);
```

I am pretty sure I am not missing any parenthesis. Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: Is `DATE(12)` a valid Oracle data type?

Comment: Basic debugging: take one part away at a time, until the error goes away. If you had tried to run that without the last column it would run fine, demonstrating that the error is in that line.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle `date` datatype does not take a length.

Consider:

```
create table CUST_ORDER (
    ord_id NUMBER(38) CONSTRAINT cusordtb_ordid_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    cust_id NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
    order_date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Date doenot take a length. So you need not specify the same

Comment: Just like GMB also mentioned, yes this does the trick. Thanks!